# how can I delete the columns contain NA or the variance equal to 0

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to `scale` my data before do a PCA, but unfortunately I found some columns contains NA, and the variance of some columns equal to 0, I want to delete these columns. This is an example of my data

```
df <- data.frame( v1 = 1:10 , v2 = rep( 0 , 10 ) , v3 = sample( c( 1:3 , NA ) , 10 , repl = TRUE ), v4 = 1:10 )
```

I want to delete the `v2` and `v3` column at the same time. how can I implement that?

I know how to delete the columns contain `NA`, and then delete the column whose variance equal to 0.

```
colsd <- apply(df, 2, sd)
df2 <- df[!is.na(colsd)]
colsd2 <- apply(df2, 2, sd)
df3 <- df2[!colsd2 == 0]
```

but it looks redundancy, I just want to know  can I implement this more efficient, maybe just in one line. Thank you for any response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
> df[!sapply(df, var) %in% c(0, NA)]
   v1 v4
1   1  1
2   2  2
3   3  3
4   4  4
5   5  5
6   6  6
7   7  7
8   8  8
9   9  9
10 10 10
```

Comment: Ah... nice, because `var` will return `NA` if there are any `NA` values. I considered a much longer possibility that was more explicit, but this is genius.

Comment: Putting on my super pedant hat, I might point out that `var(c(1.0000000000000001,rep(1,1e6))) == 0` returns `TRUE`. But this small degree of variance is going to be useless for a PCA / FA anyway.